# Why I'm getting over my firestore usage limits

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase/Angular to build my web app

I get this error : **You have gone over your daily usage limits**

But when I checked out my daily usage I get this : 3.5K reads, so I did not reached the max of free usage which is 50000 reads.

[image]

When checking out the state of my daily usage in the billing quota, I found my self reaching 100% of free reads.

[image]

I can't understand why I'm not getting the same result of my usage (reads) in the same project !!

Comment: StackOverflow is for code-based problems. This type of request should be directed to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact). They'll have the tools to be able to look into what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this as a community wiki. As suggested by @samthecodingman
above in the comments.

These types of questions are outside of the scope of StackOverflow. Please contact [firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) for this type of issue as it requires more in-depth analysis.